# Не устанавливается флажок checked (radio button) в onChange

Tags: javascript, html5, reactjs

Я в React JS новый, хотел бы кое что уточнить
Код есть, в базе данных все корректно меняется при нажатии на кнопку.
Проблема лишь в том, что оно не check-ается по внешнему виду(на фронт енде) не ясно какое значение стоит
Как исправить, подскажите пожалуйста.

Вот собственно код:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user : props.user,
        };

        this.sexChange = this.sexChange.bind(this);
    }

    sexChange(event){
        Loader.startProgress();
        Http.postJson("/profile/update-data",{
            genderUser : event.target.value
        },(body,status,response) => {
            if(response.status === 202){
                this.setState({ user : body });
            }
            Loader.stopProgress();
        },(response) => {
            Loader.stopProgress();
            Dialog.alert("Не удалось изменить");
        });
    }

 <div className="user-sex">
     <div className="radio">
         <label>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="1" onChange={this.sexChange} checked={ person.genderUser && person.genderUser.id == 1 } />
           <div>М</div>
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="2" onChange={this.sexChange} checked={ person.genderUser && person.genderUser.id == 2 }/>
            <div>Ж</div>
         </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

что я делаю не так?

Comment: `person.genderUser && person.genderUser.id` вот эти переменные в твоем коде ни где не объявлены

Comment: да я бы не сказал, он обьявлен в другом месте. но он именно не обрабатывает checked. может надо сделать this.genderUser===1?

Comment: Смотря где объявлен так и надо написать,  обычно это state учитывая что он еще и меняется

Comment: типа по дефоолту установить в getstate? я уже сделал и внес изменение в саму функцию sexGender, и сделал как предлагал нижеследующий человек, ничего пока не выходит @LevShportak . спасибо вам за вашу помощь. Если есть кое какие еще догадки добавляйте. Я еще подумаю сам )

Answer (score 1):

Не зная всей логики твоего кода

```
this.state = {
            user : props.user,
            genderUser:1

        };
```

В функцию `sexChange()` добавь `this.setState({ genderUser : event.target.value })`
В `checked={ this.state.genderUser === 1 }`

Comment: сделал, но ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 0):

> На этапе рендеринга атрибут `checked` полей ввода переопределяет
>   значение в DOM. С неуправляемым компонентом зачастую нужно, чтобы
>   React определил первоначальное значение, но впоследствии ничего не
>   делал с ним. В этом случае необходимо определить атрибут
>   `defaultСhecked` вместо `checked`.

Пример кода (согласно Вашему коду), работающего без побочного эффекта:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = { checked: 1 };
    
    this.setGender = this.setGender.bind(this);
  }
  
  setGender(event) {
    console.log('Selected gender value: ', event.target.value);
    this.setState({ checked: event.target.value });
  }
  
  render() {
    const { checked } = this.state;
    return ( 
      <div>
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            value="1"
            name="gender"
            onChange={this.setGender}
            defaultChecked={checked == 1}
          />
          <span>Male</span>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            value="2"
            name="gender"
            onChange={this.setGender}
            defaultChecked={checked == 2}
          />
          <span>Female</span>
        </label>
      </div>
     )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Для решения проблемы нужно использовать аттрибут `defaultChecked` вместо `checked`.

Ссылки для ознакомления:

- [Неуправляемые компоненты](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)
- [Управляемые компоненты](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)